# H (x ◦ id) ∈ Y1, where id = 100-bit value and Y1 = 1000-bit values or where id = 1000-bit value and Y2 = 100-bit values. Longer time?

Tags: hash, cryptography

Which one will take longer time to solve?

Assume H is a puzzle-friendly, cryptographic hash function.
My answer was A and my explanation :

A will take longer to solve.

Time taken to solve a puzzle friendly hash function depends on size of Y rather than the size of id.
It is expressed as function of number of bits in Y.

t≈2n, where t is the time taken and n is the number of bits in Y.
 As the size of Y1 > Y2, A will take longer to solve.

Apparently, the right answer is B. Why? 
I asked around for an explanation but I am not satisfied with answers.

Answer I received -

1. Y2 is set of 100-bit values i.e. target has smaller range of values than the other option means more computations to reach the result.
2. The key has a larger value than the other option which has means combinations and therefore takes longer to solve.

But I am still unclear. Please help a beginner?

Comment: Your question is off topic here, but the way it is described you can post it at [crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) - but do delete your answer here after copying as it is not about programming. You can use the edit button to get to the text of the body, and don't forget to copy the title as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is solely about cryptography without involving programming.